# How can we disable a button in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable a button using Jquery depend on a value.The button get disabled in IE 8.But in Google chrome its not get disabled.

Code.

```
 function fill(result) {
    debugger;
    $("#divSummary").dialog("open");
    $("#divSummary").html(result.Records);
    if (result.Edit== "0") {
        $('#EditSummary').attr("disabled", true);// This button not disabled in google  chrome
        return false;
    }
    else
        $('#EditSummary').attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Comment: Use .prop() and correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't it be `prop("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: @DaveHogan No, you should use boolean using .prop(). Because even you set only disabled inline attribute without value will disable element (HTML5)

Answer (score 2):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
function fill(result) {
    debugger;
    $("#divSummary").dialog("open");
    $("#divSummary").html(result.Records);
    if (result.Edit== "0") {
        $('#EditSummary').prop("disabled", true);
        return false;
    }
    else
        $('#EditSummary').prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between these two

Comment: Difference between attr() and prop() for disabled you mean?

Comment: Ya, attr() is for default attribute setted inline. .prop() reflect property. On some browser, changing programmatically attribute with .attr() will not affect property. Even some kind of attributes can react differently. So for constitency between browser, you should always use .prop().

Comment: @roasted .prop also not disabling the button

Comment: Are you sure: result.Edit== "0" returns true? I mean, is it passing this condition?  BTW, could you provide a jsfiddle or at least post relevant html code?